# Rendering Template / Components from multiple routes on single Template

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes

I've been pouring over the docs for Ember and while they are well done, they seem to be lacking from a cookbook persective of bringing all the pieces together. If I have a list of items that can be added to my cart, I am trying to build a page that lists the items (this is done and working) but I want a sidebar that shows all the items in my cart.

I have the following routes:

```
export default Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index');
    this.route('items');
    this.route('cart');
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.find('item');
    }
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
       return this.store.find('cart');
    }
});
```

Now, I'm at a loss as to how to show both my items and my cart on a single template; in essence, calling 2 routes for a single template/

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for using data-fetching components.

In my opinion, the data retrieved via a route is the one guided by the URL (in your case I suspect it's `items`). The cart is more of a URL-independent state.

I would build a `CartComponent` that has its own `store` instance injected as a service.

Incidentally, I recently wrote about this exact situation. If you are interested in pursuing this route (no pun intended!) check out http://emberigniter.com/should-components-load-data/

Comment: Great article! Thanks for sharing it. I like the fact that ember is so opinionated and the devs really drive that home, but this is one of those situations where "it is an anti-pattern only until we say it isn't".

Comment: I came across this question again by chance. A newer and more accurate article regarding this issue is available! http://emberigniter.com/load-multiple-models-single-route/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `modelFor` to refer to another route's model within your route.

For instance, you can do the following:

```
model: function() {
   return Object.create({
     cart: this.store.find('cart'),
     items: this.modelFor('item')
   });
}
```

Link to documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor